# How to remove boot from MacMini?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, startup

I have tried installing windows 7 on my MacMini.

I followed following steps.

- Setup went perfectly But while installing I thought of ***not installing*** it.
- So, I just ***restarted*** mac mini.
- Pressed ***Alt key while booting***
- Started ***OSX***
- Launched ***Disk Utility***
- ***Removed*** windows partition.

But after doing all these stuff, I am facing new problem. Each time when macMini starts, I always have to press ALT while booting, otherwise it goes in indeterminate state.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in the boot manager (the one when you press <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> on startup), click on the arrow (for the Mac OS X partition). The boot priority should then default to the Mac OS X one.

Otherwise, you can try going to the Startup Disk preference pane in System Preferences, and try setting it (by restarting).

Answer (score 2):

According to [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2336149?start=0&tstart=0) you could also have removed the Windows partition with Boot Camp Assistant (located in /Applications/Utilities).  It may be worth trying that just in case not everything was properly cleaned up during your attempts.

After that you can use go to your System Preferences, and select your OS X volume as the startup disk.