# Issues with Bootcamp trying to boot to a bootable device other than my HD

Tags: snow-leopard, bootcamp, windows, partition

A week ago, I attempting to load Windows (with Boot Camp) on my Mac Pro. The Windows 7 install CD I used had missing files, and thus I deleted the partition I created to house windows, not wanting to waste space on my hard drive. Eventually, I decided to to use bootcamp, and now, whenever I start my computer, there is a message that states: "No bootable device, insert boot disk and press any key", or something similar. Of course, I can hold alt/option or X at startup, but I don't want to have to do that every time I start up my computer, because normally I forget. Do you have any suggestions on how to stop this phenomena from occurring every time that I start my computer? (Note that I am looking for solutions - I understand why this is occurring)

Comment: so I assume that Windows is not installed?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: try going to system preferences and set the startup disk to your mac os x partition. also see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16768/how-to-remove-boot-from-macmini/16771#16771)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know there was a preference pane for that. Thanks. Would you mind posting it as an answer such that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are booting directly to your Boot Camp partition, showing you the `No bootable device, insert boot disk and press any key` message (probably due to the BIOS emulation)

To fix this, go to System Preferences and select Startup Disk. Select the appropriate disk and restart.

[image: syspref-startupdisk]