# Bootcamp fail stuck at no bootable device (hold option not working)

Tags: bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

I've been trying to find an answer to my problem all day with no luck.

I tried installing windows 7 via bootcamp this morning. I accidentally created the partition before creating a bootable usb drive with the copy of windows 7 on it.  Now when I boot up my mac, it goes to an empty grey screen then goes into the "no bootable device" screen.  I have tried pressing and holding option once I power on the laptop but that still takes me to the same "no bootable device" screen.  I am currently in the process of creating an EFI bootable usb and hoping that this will work.

Is there something I haven't tried yet?

Comment: How did you create the partition? See if this helps - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/issues-with-bootcamp-trying-to-boot-to-a-bootable-device-other-than-my-hd?rq=1

Comment: When you "created" the partition, how did you do that? And did you try the cmd-r to restore os x ?

Comment: What is the model identifier or Model/Screen Size/Year of your Mac? Define EFI bootable usb? Is that a Recovery partition on a flash drive or a complete OS X on an external hard disk? Do you have another Mac and do you know how to boot in Target disk mode? If your Mac is new enough, you can try the internet boot: hold cmd-alt-r keys at startup to boot from internet. The real question is: How exactly did you create the partition before creating a bootable usb drive? Did you use Boot Camp Assistant, the Disk Utility or something from Microsoft?

Comment: What did you do to resolve this? I have the same issue and have had no luck working around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the NVRAM, the Mac should find the first Mac OS bootbale volume and start.  If not, you can power down and try the option key again.

If that fails, your Mac boot volume is broken or your hardware is broken. Try booting to Recovery HD or internet recovery at that point to reinstall your Mac OS on top of your old Mac user and data.